# How can implement stack view?

Tags: swift, uistackview

I'm using `UIStackView` in my `Storyboard`, but I can't understand how I can set `constrains` in `UIStackview`. How to implement `Stackview` in `Storyboard` using `Autolayout` in **Swift**?

Comment: Refer this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview

Answer (score 0):

The question is really generic. Can you be more specific, what kind of layout your are trying to achieve with the StackView.

**Anyhow let me try to answer:**

> how can set constrains in stack view ?

StackView is a container/layout, generally used to arrange other UIViews. 
You only need to constraint the StackView to the container view, the child views that are added to the stack are managed based on Axis, Distribution, Spacing, etc.

- **Axis:** Vertical or Horizontal orientation of child elements added to the stack.
- **Alignment:** Aligns the child element parallel to the Axis.
- **Distribution:** Aligns the child element perpendicular to the Axis.
- **Spacing:** Inter element spacing.

> How to implement stack view in storyboard using auto layout in swift ?

You can set all the parameters/values mentioned above in the storyboard from **Attribute Inspector**.

For auto layout enable the following option in your storyboard by selecting the specific controller.

[image: Enable auto layout]

For adding proper constraints that resizes, avoid using constants and concentrate more on relative constraints.

[Properly explained in OFFICIAL DOCUMENT](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/LayoutUsingStackViews.html)